# Pylint extension disables Pylance extension in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, pylance

I have been using `Pylance` for auto suggestions and completions.

Recently i added `Pylint` to help me lint my code but the moment i installed `Pylint` my `Pylance` stopped working (its not giving any auto suggestion and the different color coding for variables, imports, etc went off).

I tried to explore on my settings to figure out the issue but i am unable to do so. Below is my vs code `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "gitlens.gitCommands.skipConfirmations": [
        "fetch:command",
        "stash-push:command",
        "switch:command",
        "remote-add:command"
    ],
    "vscode-office.previewCodeHighlight.style": "github",
    "workbench.statusBar.visible": false,
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters": false,
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.ambiguousCharacters": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "pylint.importStrategy": "fromEnvironment",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [

    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [],
    "editor.fontLigatures": false
}
```

Comment: and if you disable the pylint extension, the pylance extension takes effect again?

Comment: Yes, it does @starball

Comment: I encountered this problem when I enabled the Pylint expansion, but when I restarted VSCODE, it disappeared. Can you reappear this problem stably?

Comment: Thanks @JialeDu. It worked. Post your answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I encountered this problem when I enabled the Pylint expansion, but when I restarted VSCODE, it disappeared.

I reported this issue on GitHub. Check out the link or comment about your situation.

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22458